# Is it possible to build a .Net library without version info?

Tags: .net, windows, version

I want to build a .Net Framework library without any version info data. I am targeting the v4.6.1, using the legacy project system. My goal in doing so is that the msi installer will disregard version number comparisons when deciding whether the file should be overwritten or not, and instead use its hash to do so (at least according to [windows installer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/neither-file-has-a-version-with-file-hash-check)).

Removing the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` attributes from the `AssemblyInfo.cs` didn't do the trick, as the library is built with 0.0.0.0 version number.

I can manually remove the version info data from the binary after the build, by editing the file in Visual Studio. However, I was looking for an approach that could be integrated into the build process.

In native projects, if I don't include a `VERSIONINFO` section in the `resource.rc` file, the binary is built without version number. How can I achieve the same result for a .Net library?

Comment: Which version of .NET you are using? If it is .NET Core then you could just put this in your csproj file:

<PropertyGroup>
   <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: I tried your solution in both .NET Core and .NET Framework, but it still builds the library with 0.0.0.0 version number. Also, I am targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1, using the legacy project system. I edited to question to say it.